Fixed Start Date with Dynamic End Date Filtering in Table Visual in QuickSight
The task is to create a calculated field in Quicksight where,

A fixed start date that remains constant, regardless of the date filter selection. This could be the company's inception date or any other static date you choose.

An end date that changes based on the date range selected in the date filter by the user.


For example, if the fixed start date is January 1, 2020 (company inception), and the user selects a date range in the filter from January 1, 2022 to December 31, 2022, the calculated field should show the total "Onboarded OL" from January 1, 2020 to December 31, 2022.
How can we solve this?
Tried to create calculated field but wasn't able to pass end date parameter
